# AspxGridView: How to Get Value of Keyfield or Spesific Column on the Click Event of DataItem Template Button?

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview

I have an AspxGridView and a button inside of a DataItem Template of one column.
I use Button_Click event for this button and I need to get values of current row in this event when I click on this button.
AspxGridView's events' have "e.Keys[]" or "e.KeyValue" etc properties but I couldn't find anything for the button EventArgs.
How can I get the values of columns or KeyValue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've done it with CommandArgument. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the Container.keyvalue approach like this:

```
<dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn VisibleIndex="3" Caption="Simple Hyperlink Column">
    <DataItemTemplate>
        <a id="clickElement" target="_blank" href="Default2.aspx?id=<%# Container.KeyValue%>"><%# "Show New Form, Key Field = " + Eval("CategoryID").ToString()%></a>
    </DataItemTemplate>
</dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

Sample online here:
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E993.aspx

Answer (score 0):

there are two way

1. use CommandArgument

ASP.NET

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    <DataItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btn_1" runat="server" OnClick="btn_1_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
    </DataItemTemplate>
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

And in C#

```
protected void btn_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            int Id = Convert.ToInt32((sender as Button).CommandArgument);
    }
```

This way when you use Filter not work fine

2. Second Way Use GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer

ASP.NET

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    <DataItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btn_1" runat="server" OnClick="btn_1_Click"/>
    </DataItemTemplate>
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

C#

```
 protected void btn_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     int Device_Id = Convert.ToInt32(((sender as Button).Parent as   devExpress.Web.GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer).KeyValue);
 }
```

i think second way is better